# SQL Server R2 different versions on x86 and x64?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, 64-bit, upgrade

I have the latest SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on a W2K8 server. The version number says "10.50.1600". My problem is that my backup fails to restore on the x64 machine.

I downloaded and installed the latest from Microsoft's page for a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit machine. The SQL Server 2008 R2 version on this one says "10.00.4000". Now I can't backup/restore databases between the machine. I get this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.4000. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

I used the latest downloads from this page for both machines but ended up with different versions #'s: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/ . My question is how do I update the 64-bit machine to the "10.50.1600" version number?

**EDIT:**

Exact version using "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')":

W2K8 / x86 machine = 10.50.1600.1, RTM, Express Edition with Advanced Services

W7 / x64 machine = 10.0.4000.0, SP2, Express Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Please run the following query (in both SQL installs) and update your question to detail the output: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`

Comment: Thx... added the info above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's my understanding that 10.00 signifies original 2008, i.e. NOT R2. You may want to double check what you've downloaded, and that you're actually connecting to the instance you are intending to. Here's a chart of version numbers you can reference:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions

Answer (score 3):

Check http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx to find out what version you need, then download and patch appropriately.

> The SQL Server 2008 R2 version on this
>   one says "10.00.4000"

No, it does not. 10.00.4000 is not a 2008 R2, so it can not identify as that. This is a 2008 Sp2, that is not the same as R2.

Better go back to downloading and this time download the correct one.

10.50.1600 is 2008 R2 RTM.